# Drupal content type add class to image field (on link, not on image)

Tags: templates, drupal-7, content-type

I have a content type (i.e.: Toys)
Some fields are added including an 'images'-field.
In the display settings:
1/ link image to file

"Field formatter class" will add a class to the img-tag but I want the class on the a-tag.

How?

in template.php?? preprocess_node? preprocess_image?

Please help.

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out the theme_field API at https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/theme_field/7 and look at the examples.

Drupal core's field.module is what adds classes to fields.  You can either use a function in template.php or a tpl.php file to override it.